# Erro na conversão do VARCHAR para FLOAT no PHP + SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-insert, float, varchar

Estou precisando de uma ajuda para solucionar a seguinte situação :

- Eu puxo os dados de um csv preenchido em todas as colunas e linha , não há titulo , apenas os dados .
- No meu insert via PHP não ta indo coloquei para verificar o erro e ele me retorna dizendo que deu erro na conversão de VARCHAR para FLOAT.
- Eu tentei converter no meu insert dessa forma "(Select CAST(REPLACE('$dados[2]',',','.') AS FLOAT) )"
- O campo $dados[2] ele não vem vazio .

Segue abaixo o meu código completo :

```
<?php
// inclui a conexão
session_start();
            $serverName = "IP SERVIDOR";
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>" NOME_DB", "UID"=>" USUARIO_SERVIDOR ", "PWD"=>"SENHA_SERVIDOR" );
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
                 if ($conn === false) {
                  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 $now = new DateTime();
 $data_abertura = $now->format('Ymd'); 
 $user= $_SESSION['email'];
// Abre o Arquvio no Modo r (para leitura)
$arquivo       = fopen('area\csv\importacao.csv', 'r');

// Lê o conteúdo do arquivo
while (!feof($arquivo)) {
    
    // Pega os dados da linha
    $linha = fgets($arquivo, 2048);
    
    // Divide as Informações das celulas para poder salvar
    $dados = explode(';', $linha);
   
// INSERT no Banco de Dados
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO DESCONTOS (MATRI,DEP,VL_COPAY,DATA,NOME) VALUES ('$dados[0]', '$dados[1]',(select CAST(REPLACE('$dados[2]',',','.') AS FLOAT) ),'$data_abertura','$user')";
        $params = array();
        $options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params, $options);

        }

// Fecha arquivo aberto
fclose($arquivo);

?>
```

Comment: Mas dá algum erro?

Comment: Não da erro nenhum , contudo não adiciona no banco .  Quando eu dou um echo na variável $sql , ele imprime esses insert's preenchidos na tela . Se eu copiar e colar e jogar direto no SQL ele realiza a inserção normal . Mas via PHP esse insert não está funcionando direto .

Comment: Deve sim estar dando algum erro, imprima `sqlsrv_errors()` após a tentativa de insert e veja se ele retorna uma mensagem de erro.

Comment: Deu o que já imaginava , " Erro ao converter tipo de dados varchar em float. " , contudo não consegui ajeitar . Eu tinha posto assim " (select CAST(REPLACE('$dados[2]',',','.') AS FLOAT) )"

Comment: $dados[2] já não é float? Por que não fazer assim no insert: ` (VALUES ('$dados[1]', $dados[2], ...`

Comment: Como eu pego esse dado da leitura do CSV , ele me vem como VARCHAR , so que nesse banco o campo precisa ser float . Ou seja preciso converte-lo .

Comment: O que faz ele achar que é varchar são as aspas simples que você está inserindo via PHP. Retire as aspas e passe $dados[2] diretamente como float para o SQL.

Comment: 1 - Tirando as aspas + Continuando com o replace / cast ( A funcao replace exige o(s) argumento(s))
2 - Tirando o CAST + REPLACE + ASPAS deixando apenas o $dados[2] . (Existem menos colunas na instrucaoo INSERT do que valores especificados na clausula VALUES.)

Comment: seria mais fácil converter no php e já passar o valor correto pra query, ia até facilitar o seu debug

Comment: Você provavelmente não está tratando o caso de dados2 ser vazio

Comment: O dados2 não vem vazio , pois esse csv é um csv sem titulos e todas as informações vem com dados .